# what's the meaning of ordinates of a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

In a Gaussian distribution, what's the meaning of the height (ordinate) at $x$?

according to [[1]](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/probability-distributions-python), the [funtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaDPp.png) is called the probability distribution function of a Gaussian distribution, according to [[2]](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/normal.htm), it calculates the height of a Gaussian distribution.

Does this function mean the probability at $[-\infty，x]$, or the height (ordinate)?

TIA.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when you want to define a function.

Comment: @mag OK, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you mentioned (better to write in with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13081#13081)) is NOT the probability distribution, it is the pdf: probability Density function (the ordinate, as you said).

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
f(x|\mu\;\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}
\qquad 
}
$$

The probability distribution is its integral function

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$$

Comment: I would rather call this the "probability distribution function" or "cumulative distribution function".  The term "distribution" is overloaded, and one wants to distinguish the probability law of a rv. from the various functions that can be used to describe it.  The prob law (the "distribution")  vs the cdf, or whatever.